# How to grant single user access from other computer?

Tags: windows-8, file-sharing

I own two computers running Windows 8. Both of them are configured with the same user (say Bob) and password, with admin rights. Without getting crazy, I'd like to grant ONLY the user Bob full access to the file system on both PCs.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: If Bob is admin on both machines, what makes you think Bob doesn't have full access to the file system on both machines?

Comment: It's a file sharing matter.....Bob on computer_A should access all files on computer_B and viceversa...